# OAuth2 User Credentials Grant

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0

I would just like to ask about the User Credentials Grant of OAuth2.
Does the access token returned by the server differ for every user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you refer to the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant, yes. Although it would be more specific to say that it differs for every user/Client/scopes combination.